# rails add new row in table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have read in some tutorials about adding a column to an existing table. A question came across my mind, is it possible to add an additional row in the existing table

example,

I have a table of car, with attributes of :type and :colour
and I have a method

> def mymethod_todoinsertnewrowsincartable
>   
> insert car { :type => "BMW", :colour => "blue" }
>   
> end

How can I do this in above method? thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it by following:-

```
Car.create(:type=>'BMW',:colour=>"blue")
```

Where Car is model name.

Thanks.....