# Add Rows to a SQL Table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I add data to a table in Rails?

So far I have created a Rails app that pulls in data from an API. Next, I have ran the command

```
rails generate model order
```

and I have /db/migrate/timestamp_create_orders.rb

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.string :order_date, null: false
      t.string :total_price, null: false
      t.string :order_number, null: false
      t.string :cust_name, null: false
      t.string :zip_code, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Next, I believe I need to run db:migrate and that will create the table.

My question is, how do I add data to this table? I want the user to visit the app, it pulls in the data, and stores it in this table.

I have found conflicting advice..
Should I just use the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614550/rails-add-new-row-in-table)

```
Order.create(:email=>'fake@fake.com',:order_data=>"...
```

But other advise seems to say not to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667580/how-do-i-add-some-inserts-in-rails-migration) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534682/how-can-i-insert-data-into-table-by-the-help-of-migration-and-that-table-is-gene). Though they are all pretty old

Comment: Have looked at the rails docs? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller.  Model.create() will create and save the record. Model.new() will create it and you would have to do var.save to save to the db.

Comment: Thanks. So this is best practice? I didn't really understand why some posts were saying you shouldn't use this. Only don't use it for seed data?

Comment: Are you wanting to save data coming from the api while the app its in use ( that seems to be your question the rest is setup)? Seeding a database with default data vs saving records while an app is in use are two different things (to me at least).  I would not add data to a db through a migration. Its for creating and modifying tables (db setup).  Your controller,models,api,seed,etc files would handle adding and removing data depending on your prupose/goal. Id read the whole doc page above, it explains with examples and gives context.

Comment: Sorry, to answer your question in your comment, I think thats right, they were saying not to use the create() method in migrations which are Rails' way of manipulating the database structure, but its fair in your app code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating or migrating a new database table, table `row` is not automatically added. You need to add them manually. One way to populate the newly created database table is using `seeds.rb` file which is located in your application `db` folder. You can add [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) gem to your application for creating fake table attribute elements. An example using faker:

```
(1..3).each do # it'll create  3 new order
   Order.create(email: Faker::Internet.email, order_date: Faker::Date.between(2.days.ago, Date.today))
end
```

Then run `rake db:seed` in your project folder console.

If you have some validation in your `order.rb` file, then you can create `new` instance of that `order` and then save it like:

```
order = Order.new(....)

order.save(validate: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not create database entries in migrations, you usually create schema or specify changes in the `schema` in migration files. You use `seeds` for creating seed data in the database.

To create new data in database through rails you can use either `create` or `new` method but you need to `save` the data as mentioned in other posts in your links when you are using `new` method.